# website zoom, but menu doesn't zoom

Tags: html, zooming, css-position, css

I have menu where I have used CSS as mentioned below.

```
#cssmenu {
    zoom: 1;
    font-size: 20pt;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-image: url('../images/Graphics/navigation-top-bar1.png');
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1024px 80px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Now when I zoom in safari, website zooms but menu remain as it is. Menu doesn't get zoomed.

Any idea how to activate zoom on menu too when zooming in safari?

Website link is

http://www.smartprojects-kw.com

In mobile, I see menu divided in 2-3 lines as per the zoom.

Any idea/ guess why this is happening? This is making me crazy

Comment: There are structural errors in the HTML; `<link>` and `<meta>` elements in the body and things like that,. If you correct those, does it work properly? Also, you are mixing up HTML and XHTML.

Comment: @MrLister : why link and meta will be problem for zooming?

Comment: When confronted with strange behaviour, it's always best to play it safe and check your source for errors. Especially structural errors like that!

Comment: Try removing `zoom: 1;`?

Comment: @Axel : I will check tomorrow once I reach office for sure...

Comment: @Axel : after removing zoom:1, it still not zooming